# Bitbucket create PR API request timing out

Tags: bitbucket, bitbucket-api, http-status-code-504

We've suddenly started seeing time-outs on our API-based PR creation requests in Bitbucket. I'm able to create a PR in the UI, but any attempt to do so via API results in a 504 Gateway Time-out.

We're on the free tier of Bitbucket, so I cannot submit an issue to them... Are any other Bitbucket users here experiencing this?

**Request**:

Endpoint: [https://api.bitbucket.org/2.0/repositories/{workspace}/{repo-slug}/pullrequests](https://api.bitbucket.org/2.0/repositories/%7Bworkspace%7D/%7Brepo-slug%7D/pullrequests)

```
{
  "title": "Staging merge to Release Candidate",
  "source": {
    "branch": {
      "name": "staging"
    }
  },
  "destination": {
    "branch": {
      "name": "release-candidate"
    }
  }
}
```

**Response**:

```
<html>

<head>
    <title>504 Gateway Time-out</title>
</head>

<body>
    <center>
        <h1>504 Gateway Time-out</h1>
    </center>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The bitbucket API endpoint `https://api.bitbucket.org/2.0/repositories/{workspace}/{repo-slug}/pullrequests` currently returns an 504 Gateway Time-Out when there aren't any code changes between two branches.

Source:
https://jira.atlassian.com/browse/BCLOUD-22009

Do you have changes between the branches `staging` and `release-candidate`?

Comment: Thanks! There may or may not be changes depending on if we’ve merged commits into staging since the last automated run. So, this effectively breaks the design…hopefully it gets addressed soon